# El php array_filter no me filtra bien

Tags: php, array

array(4){[0]=>cadena(3) "USD"[1]=> cadena(3) "EUR"[2]=> cadena(3) "PEN" [3]=> cadena(3) "TU"}

Tengo esta matriz de monedas.

Tengo otra matriz y necesito filtrarla con la matriz anterior.

{ "tipo":"Cascos", "nro_item":1, "tipogasto":"1", "nro_itemg":1, "codigorubro":"00001", "nombrerubro":"Manzanas", "tipomoneda":" USD", "afectoigv":"N", "afectopeso":"M", "afectocontenedor":"N", "cant":"5", "unidad":"", "tarifapublicada":115, "preciounitario ":115, "ventatotal":575, "netaorigen":575, "igv_item":0, "total_item":575, "tipomonedaoriginal":"USD", "tcambio":1, "importe":575, "igv_original ":0, "total_original":575, "swneto":"2", "editable":"S", "tarifa_maxima":"0", "tarifa_minima":"115.00", "descripcioningles":"" }, { "tipo":"Cascos", "nro_item":1, "tipogasto":"1", "nro_itemg": 1, "codigorubro":"00001", "nombrerubro":"Manzanas", "tipomoneda":"USD", "afectoigv":"N", "afectopeso":"M", "afectocontenedor":"N", "cant":"5", "unidad":"", "tarifapublicada":115, "preciounitario":115, "ventatotal":575, "netaorigen":575, "igv_item":0, "total_item":575 , "tipomonedaoriginal":"USD", "cambio":1, "importe":575, "igv_original":0, "total_original":575, "swneto":"2", "editable":"S", "tarifa_maxima":"0", "tarifa_minima":"115.00", "descripcioningles":"" },

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué código estás usando? ¿Qué resultados obtienes y qué esperas obtener? Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario y es PHP

Comment: Ya sé que es PHP, pero en la pregunta no se ve el código PHP que usas para hacer lo que quieres.

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte, debes antes intentar resolver el problema de alguna forma. Por eso te pedimos que muestres lo que hayas intentado.